# MySQL create use with permissions from anywhere fails

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL user with permissions from anywhere, but the command is failing:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user 'accounts'@'%' identified by 'password';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'accounts'@'%'
```

But if I change the permissions to access it from only localhost it works:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'accounts'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

I have a database called accounts:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases like 'accounts';
+---------------------+
| Database (accounts) |
+---------------------+
| accounts            |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

But I have to also create a user called accounts as well.

Note, I am doing this for work so I do not make decisions on who can access the DB from where.

Why does the first command fail?

Comment: runs ok as loggedin user root, you are missing some privileges for that command

Comment: Are you certain that user `'accounts'@'%'` doesn't exists? I quote from MariaDB doc   _"If any of the specified accounts, or any permissions for the specified accounts, already exist, then the server returns ERROR 1396 (HY000). If an error occurs, CREATE USER will still create the accounts that do not result in an error. Only one error is produced for all users which have not been created:"_ https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/